# How do I change the content of a column to pick from another column based on a criteria, leaving that column blank WHEN it does pick from it

Tags: powerquery, m

I need to replace the value of a column(LastName) with values from another column('MiddleName') IF column "LastName" contains "." and column B contains non null values while deleting the content of column('MiddleName') only if the content has been moved to column ("LastName").

```
NIL

NIL
```

That Column 'MiddleName' becomes blank if column "LastName" contained "." and the column 'MiddleName' (which had content) has now been moved to column "LastName".

For instance; if the columns contained;

```
MiddleName   LastName
john            .
james        phillips
Mary            .

The procedure should then make it:
MiddleName   LastName
             john 
james        phillips
             Mary
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: I have done so. please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to do with new custom columns rather than replacing the existing ones.

```
Middle = if [LastName] = "." then null else [MiddleName]

Last   = if [LastName] = "." then [MiddleName] else [LastName]
```